# In a Xcode template, what is the keyword to define the file type?

Tags: templates, keyword, xcode4.3

I created a Xcode 4.3 template which includes one file with extension `.pde`.

Automatic file type associated is `Plain text`.

I want to specify C++ as file type for this specific file in order to obtain code-sense. I do it manually on File Inspector pane with File Type right under File Name.

*Pictures: [before](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZXsS6fHLa-E/TzjnTs7wFBI/AAAAAAAAJBI/wZsE-kSliMY/s1600/default%2Btype.jpg) and [after](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-XRHfEcH3wYw/TzjnVDjrjPI/AAAAAAAAJBY/HCBM2Lc4rKU/s1600/file%2Btype.jpg)*

However, I'd like to keep `Info.plist` unchanged because I don't want to make all `.pde` files considered as C++ files.

In filetype.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj, keyword for default type is `lastKnownFileType = text`

After changing it to C++, keyword is `explicitFileType = sourcecode.cpp.cpp`

What is the keyword I could use on the template?